# Animation does not work with autolayout (swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, uiimageview, autolayout

Whenever I try to animate objects that I have programmed to the screen using autolayouts, a lot of issues arise. When I tried to animate a UIImageView, instead of transitioning to the next image it would duplicate the object. Here is the code for the layout:

```
    icon.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: circle.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    icon.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: circleView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    icon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    icon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

Here is the code for the animation:

```
private func animateIcon(){
    UIView.transition(with: icon,
                      duration: 0.75,
                      options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                      animations: { self.icon.image = UIImage(named: "CultureIcon") },
                      completion: nil)
}
```

When i add the UIImageView to screen using its frame, the animation works exactly as intended.

EDIT: I think I found the issue. I was calling the setup function for that view in viewDidLayoutSubviews(). As soon as I removed the functions from there the transitions worked.

However, I am also using the function provided by @AmberK which may have contributed to the solution!

Comment: Where you are calling `animateIcon` function?

Comment: @ivarun I created a tap gesture for the view that the UIImageView is in and call the function from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try...

```
private func animateIcon(){
self.icon.image = UIImage(named: "CultureIcon")
UIView.transition(with: icon,
                  duration: 0.75,
                  options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                  animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
                  completion: nil)
}
```

*Edit: Corrected the format*

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. The transition worked but the duplication of the objects inside the view still occurs.